# In a CSV file I have a list of machines, if inactive in AD remove it from the file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that contains 2 fields, 1. ComputerName 2. ErrorCode. It is created from a security application.

I need to compare the list of ComputerName to AD. If it is active I need it to export to another CSV file.

Sounds simple enough but I can't figure how to also write the error message to the same file. If I could read AD and simply delete the rows that don't exist, that would be great too, but I already have most of what I need.

I can separate the list into machines that exist in AD and the ones that don't with the code I have so far but it doesn't copy the error message.

***Edit for more clarification***

In `database-1.csv`:

```
Computername,Error
4140lw7,Systems Partion too small
```

When I run the script the output looks like the following and doesn't remove inactive machines;

```
4140lw7,System Partition too small
```

The script I am using will separate what is active in AD from what is not, but only if the Error column doesn't exist, i.e. `database-1.csv` w/o Error column:

```
ComputerName
2sd8cfngw98
23987hgivuw
```

This will create the following:

`exist.csv` (active in AD):

```
2sd8cfngw98
```

`nonexist.csv` (inactive in AD):

```
23987hgivuw
```

But it will not work if the error code is in the file. I need the error code in the file that is associated with the machine name.

```
foreach ($computer in (Get-Content C:\apps\database-1.csv)) {
    try {
        $test = Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -ErrorAction Stop
        if ($test) {
            Write-Output "$computer" | Out-File C:\apps\exist.csv -Append
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Output "$computer" | Out-File C:\apps\Nonexist.csv -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: So database-1.csv is a csv containing two columns. You read it using Get-Content and each line is a computer name. I think you need to use Import-CSV instead of Get-Content. Please provide a sample of the contents of database-1.csv

Comment: What error message? Please provide sample input as well as samples of the desired output for an existing and a missing computer.

Comment: also to write the error you can use `2>filename.txt` or look into `write-error`

Comment: Gert, Yes and yes. But it is currently working with just the machine names. I just don't know how to also ensure the error code is exported as well. Sample content is as explained column A has a list of machine names, Colunm B has and error code i.e.  "Systems Partition too small".

Comment: Ansgar, Robert, There is no error. As explained it is working. But it is only using the computername column.

Comment: Quoting from your question: *"but I can't figure how to also write the error message to the same file"* So, again, what error message? Also, again, please [edit] your question and provide the 3 samples I asked you to provide.

Comment: The Error message is not a PS error. It is an error from the output of another application. I posted to clarify, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of comparing the output files:

```
Compare-Object -DifferenceObject (Get-Content file1.txt ) -ReferenceObject (Get-Content file2.txt ) -PassThru |
    Out-File file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to read your input file as a CSV (`Import-Csv`), not as a plain text file (`Get-Content`), because the latter will give you the entire line (including the error message) whereas the former will give you access to both fields separately.

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
foreach ($computer in (Import-Csv 'C:\input.csv')) {
    if (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$($_.ComputerName)'") {
        $_ | Export-Csv 'C:\exist.csv' -NoType -Append
    } else {
        $_ | Export-Csv 'C:\nonexist.csv' -NoType -Append
    }
}
```

However, depending on the number of computers in your AD and the number of records in your input CSV this won't scale very well, because AD queries are expensive. Only use this approach if you have a very small number of entries in your CSV compared to the total number of computers in AD.

Generally a better approach is to build a hashtable from your AD computers:

```
$computers = @{}
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object { $computers[$_.Name] = $true }
```

allowing you an inexpensive lookup of the computer names.

```
foreach ($computer in (Import-Csv 'C:\input.csv')) {
    if ($computers.ContainsKey($_.ComputerName)) {
        $_ | Export-Csv 'C:\exist.csv' -NoType -Append
    } else {
        $_ | Export-Csv 'C:\nonexist.csv' -NoType -Append
    }
}
```

Querying all computers from AD takes comparatively long compared to querying just a single computer, but the execution time for that is more or less constant, whereas with individual queries the execution time is proportional to the number of queries. Like this:

```
  ^
t |
  |                ,´
  |              ,´ individual queries
  |            ,´
  |          ,´
  |        ,´
  |------,´---------- 
  |    ,´           query all
  |  ,´
  |,´
  +-------------------->
                      n
```

In the above rough diagram `t` is the script execution time and `n` the number of entries in the input CSV.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!